# Generate script for large table SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I generate large table scripts ( data only) in sql server 2012?

-- Have approximately 116463 rows selected after seelect query was cancelled.could      be more than that

Please suggest.

Comment: And what exactly is this script expected to do?  You don't give anywhere near enough information to go on.

Comment: @siyual insert statements for each row that table has

Comment: So you're wanting to generate an `INSERT` statement for each record in a table?  Can you elaborate a bit on why you're wanting to do this?  There might be a more elegant solution to your actual issue.

Comment: @siyual i wanted to have backup for database. but not able to copy backup file from server itself. and i cant get it done. so i m trying to run the scripts and then running that scripts on my local database. but some of the tables are really large and it doesnt generate scripts.

Comment: If you're unable to access the backup files, I would recommend using SSIS to migrate the data tables to your local machine.  It is far more efficient than generating large scripts, plays well with SQL Server (you can  enable it from the SQL Server installation on your local machine), and is easy to use.

Comment: Can you please suggest more details about SSIS. I have never used it. if you can share link it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To do large amounts of just data the bcp Utility may be of a lot of help it can export data very quickly.  It is through the cmd prompt but it is very clean and fast

It is a bulk copy.

This is the information from Microsoft
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look into DTS Wizard.   It is fast, easy and just right for such one time jobs.  You can control where the data goes to, including another SQL Server, Excel, CSV, etc....   And, if needed, move the data in reverse, from your backup medium back into the original database.  DTS Wizard...don't go anywhere without it.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your database in the Object Explorer
2. Choose Tasks
3. Choose Export Data to bring up the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard and pick your source (DB and table or query) and destination.

Comment: And it crashed on you? if so, you could probably use a query (the Export Data wizard has an option for that) to load a subset of records - basically do it pieces.

Comment: Well i used BCP utility and it didnt crash for even 800MB file. I was able to run that on my local using the same!!